# How do I map a subclass of a parent class that has no table

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables in my database that home data for a superclass and a subclass. However, in my application, I have an intermediate class between the two that gets its data loaded from bottom subclass...

```
abstract public class TierSettings
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string SomeTierSetting { get; set; }
}

abstract public class PricingStrategy : TierSettings
{
    public string StrategySetting1 { get; set; }
    public string StrategySetting2 { get; set; }
}

public class FirstPricingStrategy : PricingStrategy 
{
    public PricingStrategyType Strategy { get { return PricingStrategyType.Strategy1; } }
    public Decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class SecondPricingStrategy : PricingStrategy 
{
    public PricingStrategyType Strategy { get { return PricingStrategyType.Strategy2; } }
    public Decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

In my database I just have 2 tables:

```
TierSettings(
    Id Guid Primary Key,
    SomeTierSetting NVarChar(100)
)

PricingStrategies(
    Id Guid Primary Key, Foreign Key References Parent(Id),
    StrategySetting1 NVarChar(100),
    StrategySetting2 NVarChar(100),
    StrategyType Int,
    Value Float
)
```

I'm having problems mapping the relationships in my hbm.xml file. If I map the individual PricingStrategy classes as extending Tier, I don't have access to StrategySetting properties ... but my PricingStrategy class doesn't map to the database directly.

I need to be able to query such:

```
var items = from items in session.Query<TierSettings>() select item;

foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

How can I structure my mapping file accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 'table per concrete subclass' pattern

[Table per concrete subclass pattern](http://ajlopez.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/nhibernate-3-part-3-table-per-concrete-class/)

Comment: Thanks, I'd already looked at this, but either I'm missing something or it doesn't take into account the fact that I have a table roughly assimimilating my top level abstract class. I can't quite connect the dots between where I am and where I need to get to... can you provide any further explanation?